# Python - Time Delay in Function

Tags: python, delay, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm using python to create a game like 'Space Invaders' (I'm using **Turtle**). I'm trying to make the enemy shoot every 5 seconds. this is the fuction I'm using:

```
def fire_missile():
    n = random.randint(0, 30)
    x = enemies[n].xcor()
    y = enemies[n].ycor() - 10
    if y < 300:
        play_sound("laser.wav")
        missile.setposition(x, y)
        missile.showturtle()
    else:
        fire_missile()
```

I have 30 enemies, so this function searchs for an enemy between a certain position. and then makes it shoot.

The problem is that I can't find a good way to make a delay only in that function. I've tried using `time.sleep(5)` or `threading.Timer(5.0, fire_missile).start()` but this makes my whole code stops.
(I didn't use those at the same time). Oh, I also tried binding the function to a key in my keyboard using `screen.onkeypress(fire_missile, "m")` to check if the function worked, and it did.
I really don't know why, when I call the function with `threading.Timer` it doesn't work.

I hope you can understand my problem and thanks in advance!

PD: I'm not very good at speaking English, so sorry if there is something grammatically wrong in this question ;)

Comment: Are you already using any threading or multiprocessing to be able to do more than one thing at once?

Comment: @HansMusgrave No, I'm not. Actually at the end of the script I have a `while True: `. This is because I need some functions to run the whole time

Comment: Search StackOverflow for questions regarding Space Invaders and turtle.  There's fifty of them, some of which will likely have this same issue.  Hint: `while True:` has no business in an object-oriented environment like turtle.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

If you have an update loop in the game, you can consider doing something like this

```
import time

global g_last_missile_fired
g_last_missile_fired = 0
MISSILE_DELAY = 5

def main():
    # Initialize with game start time
    global g_last_missile_fired
    g_last_missile_fired = time.time()

    while True:
        update()

def update():
    # Other update code
    # ...
    
    # Missile code
    global g_last_missile_fired
    if time.time() >= (g_last_missile_fired + MISSILE_DELAY):
        g_last_missile_fired = time.time()
        fire_missile()

def fire_missile():
    print("Fired!")

main()
```

## Solution 2

You can call the `fire_missile()` function every `update()` with a timer-check within, or build a `queue`, or `deque`, and monitor that in `update()`.

Comment: At the end of my script I'm using a `while True:` statement and next to it `screen.update()`. Is that "update" what you mean?

Comment: Yes! Try to inject the `# Missile code` section in there

Comment: Its kind of working. Now I can "play" while the function runs, but it runs extremely fast. I tried using a higher number for `MISSILE_DELAY` but it keeps doing the same. I tried printing `time.time()` to know what it was. This was the result: `1595864016.2519414` I think I should restart the time everytime I start a new game. But that might not be the solution.

Comment: @PedroElizaldeAcevedo I've updated the code to fix – my bad :) If your code has a "new game" option to start the game, you can move `# Initialize with game start time` to where the new game is started